# MySQL SubQuery with Count: Results are not correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this individual MySQL query which produces the table I want to see. 
This shows a count of post roman pottery fabrics in a particular archaeological phase.

```
  SELECT
  post_roman_pot.PRP_Fabric,
  Count(post_roman_pot.PRP_Fabric) AS count,
  post_roman_pot.Site_id,
  context_register.Phase
FROM
  post_roman_pot
  INNER JOIN context_register ON post_roman_pot.Site_Code = context_register.Site_Code AND post_roman_pot.Context =
    context_register.Context
WHERE
  post_roman_pot.Site_id = 6 AND
    context_register.Phase = 'fen14-ph12'
GROUP BY
  post_roman_pot.PRP_Fabric
ORDER BY
  post_roman_pot.PRP_Fabric
;
```

What I want to see is counts of fabrics in all phases in one table. I could just keep running the query and change the phase number in the 'where' column but I want to see if I can do it as one table.

This is the best I've come up with. The syntax is wrong, I just can't work out how to do it.Perhaps someone could be kind enough show me what i'm doing wrong. I've added just two phases.

```
    select 
post_roman_pot.site_id,
post_roman_pot.prp_fabric,
(select count(post_roman_pot.prp_fabric) from post_roman_pot where       post_roman_pot.Site_id = 6 AND context_register.Phase = 'fen14-ph12' )as 'Phase12'
(select count(post_roman_pot.prp_fabric) from post_roman_pot where post_roman_pot.Site_id = 6 AND context_register.Phase = 'fen14-ph13' )as 'Phase13'
from post_roman_pot 
INNER JOIN context_register ON post_roman_pot.Site_Code = context_register.Site_Code AND post_roman_pot.Context =
    context_register.Context
 where post_roman_pot.site_id=6
 group by post_roman_pot.prp_fabric
 order by post_roman_pot.prp_fabric
 ;
```

Example data. This would be an example of results from the first query: 
(not sure how you invoke html table)

```
PRP_Fabric, count, Site_id, Phase
BORDB     ,     3,       6, FEN14-PH12
BORDG     ,     3,       6, FEN14-PH12
BORDG CHP2,     3,       6, FEN14-PH12
BORDO     ,    12,       6, FEN14-PH12
```

The results of the combined query would be something like

```
Site_id, PRP_Fabric, Phase12 {count}, Phase 13 {count}
6,       BORDB,        3,              2
6,       BORDG,        3,              0
6,       BORDG CHP2,   3,              6
6,       BORDO,        12,             0
```

So I've worked out what the syntax error was - bracket in the wrong place. 
The results the query shows to me is 507 where a fabric is present against the phase. 507 is the number of fabrics in the dataset for site 6.

So the above results appear like this:

```
Site_id, PRP_Fabric, Phase12 {count}, Phase 13 {count}
6,       BORDB,        507,              507
6,       BORDG,        507,              0
6,       BORDG CHP2,   507,              507
6,       BORDO,        507,              0
```

Therefore there is something out of place with the query.

Comment: What happens if a Roman pot is found?

Comment: Can you please provide example tables and data?

Comment: example shown. not sure how to do a table in this forum

Comment: Roman pot wouldn't be found as it is recorded in a different table

Comment: Please provide data sample for context_register too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one result row per site and fabric, so these are the columns you group by. Then you want to count per phase. In order to do this, use conditional aggregation, i.e. count over a case expression:

```
select
  prp.site_id,
  prp.prp_fabric,
  count(case when cr.phase = 'fen14-ph12' then 1 end) as phase12,
  count(case when cr.phase = 'fen14-ph13' then 1 end) as phase13
from post_roman_pot prp
join context_register cr on prp.site_code = cr.site_code and prp.context = cr.context
group by prp.site_id, prp.prp_fabric
order by prp.site_id, prp.prp_fabric;
```

In MySQL where `true = 1` and `false = 0`, you can count with `sum` and make this a tad more readable maybe:

```
select
  prp.site_id,
  prp.prp_fabric,
  sum(cr.phase = 'fen14-ph12') as phase12,
  sum(cr.phase = 'fen14-ph13') as phase13
from post_roman_pot prp
join context_register cr on prp.site_code = cr.site_code and prp.context = cr.context
group by prp.site_id, prp.prp_fabric
order by prp.site_id, prp.prp_fabric;
```

Comment: Excellent. That is it exactly thank you very much Thorsten Kettner. Two things i didn't know about - using case and I didn't know could abbreviate the table name like that. I'm going to have to go back to the manual and have another read.

Answer (score 0):

Just group by context_register.Phase

```
 SELECT
  Count(post_roman_pot.PRP_Fabric) AS count,
  post_roman_pot.Site_id,
  context_register.Phase
FROM
  post_roman_pot
  INNER JOIN context_register ON post_roman_pot.Site_Code = context_register.Site_Code AND post_roman_pot.Context =
    context_register.Context
WHERE
  post_roman_pot.Site_id = 6
GROUP BY
  context_register.Phase
;
```

Comment: `..., site_id;`

Comment: that query would get the total fabric counts per phase. not quite what i'm aiming for  but thanks.